# How to output enum elements using cout?

Tags: c++, enums

I am trying to output a element of enum I declared but for example, when I input push_ups, it outputs a number like 8621623 instead of showing push_ups. I have no idea why. I am Japanese so I am sorry if my English is broken. Thank you so much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum exercise { push_ups, sit_ups, squats, walking, radio_calisthenics };

istream& operator>>(istream& is, exercise& i)
{
    int tmp;
    if (is >> tmp)
        i = static_cast<exercise>(tmp);
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    exercise a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Wait, to clarify, what exactly did you enter? If you entered the string "push_ups", note that this has no meaning for the algorithm. Most likely, you'd need to enter something like 0 to get the enum value `push_ups`. Enums don't carry string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to output a element of enum I declared but for example, when I input `push_ups`, it outputs a number like `8621623` instead of showing `push_ups`.

In the `operator>>` overload, `std::cin` accepts *integers* so `push_ups` isn't an integer, so `std::cin` will fail and and the line `i = static_cast<exercise>(tmp);` will be skipped making `a` uninitialized which when printed can cause *Undefined Behavior* to occur.

If you want to map *strings* to respective enum values, you could do that by mapping each string to the corresponding enum values manually using a hashmap (In C++, that container is called [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)):

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>

// ...

const unordered_map<string, exercise> exercise_map {
    { "push_ups", push_ups },
    { "sit_ups", sit_ups },
    { "squats", squats },
    { "walking", walking },
    { "radio_calisthenics", radio_calisthenics }
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, exercise& i) {
    std::string tmp;
    if (is >> tmp) {
        auto const it = exercise_map.find(tmp);
        if (it != exercise_map.end())
            i = it->second;
    }
    return is;
}
```

Now, to print out the corresponding *string* value from the enum, we have to do the reverse, i.e., find the key in the hashmap using the value:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, exercise& i) {
    auto const it = std::find_if(exercise_map.begin(), exercise_map.end(),
        [i](std::pair<std::string, exercise> const& e) {
            return e.second == i;
        }
    );
    if (it != exercise_map.end())
        os << it->first;
    return os;
}
```

This is how the full code should look like:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum exercise { push_ups, sit_ups, squats, walking, radio_calisthenics };

const std::unordered_map<std::string, exercise> exercise_map {
    { "push_ups", push_ups },
    { "sit_ups", sit_ups },
    { "squats", squats },
    { "walking", walking },
    { "radio_calisthenics", radio_calisthenics }
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, exercise& i) {
    std::string tmp;
    if (is >> tmp) {
        auto const it = exercise_map.find(tmp);
        if (it != exercise_map.end())
            i = it->second;
    }
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, exercise& i) {
    auto const it = std::find_if(exercise_map.begin(), exercise_map.end(),
        [i](std::pair<std::string, exercise> const& e) {
            return e.second == i;
        }
    );
    if (it != exercise_map.end())
        os << it->first;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    exercise a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`push_ups` is not a valid integer value that you are trying to read at `is >> tmp` so `a` remains uninitialized. If you want to input names then you'll need to read string and then manually convert it to corresponding enum value. Same for output. Without a properly overloaded operator << `a` will be treated as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have problems with understanding `enum`s.
I think you entered the string value "push_ups" and assumed the program would understand it to refer to a value of your `enum`.
An `enum` is just a placeholder for an integer type, mostly used to increase the  readability of your program.

See an enum to be a better way to express something like

```
// chess_piece = 1 : pawn
// chess_piece = 2 : rook
// chess_piece = 3 : bishop
...
int chess_piece;
```

as

```
enum ChessPiece { Pawn, Rook, Bishop, ...};
ChessPiece chess_piece;
```

In the upper variant, it is clear that the names pawn, rook etc are *comment only*. The `enum` isn't different in that regard. It is clearly more readable to write `if(chess_piece == Pawn)`, but the word "Pawn" is only a part of the code in the programming language, *not in the compiled program*. It does not exist as string value.

What you can do is to add something like

```
exercise exercise_from_string(const std::string& input)
{
     if(input == "push_ups") return push_ups;
     ...
```

Or the same with a switch. I'd also advise that you have a value "unknown" in case a function like that finds no known term.

Edit: One of the other guys updated his answer while I wrote this, his code using a `std::map` is better than mine.
Hope my answer helps you understanding the core issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

this line here:

```
i = static_cast<exercise>(tmp);
```

will work perfectly when tmp is holding an int value between 0 and 4,

but in your case tmp = push_ups is breaking the cast operation and your ref **i** is wrongly initialized